# Function "overruns" the if-else statement during execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, if-statement, asynchronous

I have the following function:

```
function updateChatRoom() {
$.post('php/api.php', {"function":"getActiveChat"}, function(jsData) {
    var chatID = jsData.id;
    if (chatID == 0) {
        alert('no active chat!');
    }
    else {
        $.post('php/api.php', {"function":"updateChatRoom", "chatID":chatID}, function(jsData) {
            $('#chatRoom').empty();
            length = jsData.length;
            for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
                $('#chatRoom').append('\
                    <div class="fe-message-wrap">\
                        <div class="fe-message-name">'+ jsData[i].name + ':</div>\
                        <div class="fe-message-text">'+ jsData[i].message +'</div>\
                    </div>\
                ').fadeIn('250');
            }
            $('#chatRoom').scrollTop($('#chatRoom')[0].scrollHeight).animate('500');
            $('#chatMessage').focus();
        });
    }
});
```

}

When this function is executed, it should first checked if there is a active chat. This is tested by the api call "getActiveChat".
This returns 0, if there is no active chatroom.
My problem is, that even if there returns 0 ind chatID, it just ignores the whole if-else statement and jumps right into the next $.post() function... ???? How that?
I don't get this, what's wrong?

Any hints?

Comment: Ah, I added a log entry after "var chatID = jsData.id;". The result is: unknown. So it seems like he doenst assign the result of the $.post query to the variable chatID.... Why???

Comment: `console.log(typeof chatID)` to find out what variable type it is, you're comparing it to `int` zero, so if `chatID` is a string it will fail

Comment: replace by   `if (parseInt(chatID) == 0) {`

Comment: If you pass your code through [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) it will tell you "always use === when comparing to zero"

Comment: Also this looks problematic (again JSHint told me so) `length = jsData.length`

Comment: When I do: `var chatID = parseInt(jsData.id)` the log will say it's a number. But the if condition still ignores it, even when I make `chatID ===0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if `chatID` is a string. In javascript `0 == false` but `"0" == true`.

---

Now that you mentioned that the value of `chatID` is undefined, you've found the reason. Because in javascript, `undefined != 0`.

Check to see what `jsData` is. If it is a string then you need to do a `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object.

Comment: handling the 0 as a string doesn't work. it's not a string. consoles says undefined...

Comment: Undefined is the same since `undefined != 0`

Comment: OK, `if (chatID != 0)` fixed it, it now works... but can anyone explain why?

Comment: If `chatID` is undefined if there's no active chat but is a number if there is an active chat then a better check is to simply do `if (!chatID)`. `!chatID` covers both the case that it is undefined and that it is zero.